# How to change size of div on which the image is being displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design

I am using high charts to generate the stacked bar.
This is my div -

```
  <div id="container" style="min-width: 2000px; height: 3000px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Here how I can change this div size on every **click-event** in such a away that the image size also grows with the div size.

Please guide

Comment: You don't need to resize the div as if the image size is increased the div size is increased accordingly as assuming overflow: visible and height: auto

Comment: yea thats right, but here image size won't increase. I want to give a option to user to increase the image size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever `<img>` you have in your `<div id="container">` set it to

```
img {
    display:block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

If you're using Boostrap, you can just add the `img-responsive` class to your `<img>`

EDIT

Ok, so if you want the chart to resize and fit your new container width and height, you should call that method: `$( "#container" ).highcharts().reflow();` after you're done resizing your div

If you add a `<button id="test">TEST</button>`

you can do this:

```
$('#test').on("click",  function () {
    $( "#container" ).width( $( "#container" ).width() + 500 );
    $( "#container" ).height( $( "#container" ).height() + 500 );
    $( "#container" ).highcharts().reflow();
});
```

Make sure you have the jQuery js loaded for it to work :)

Comment: Thankx for your input, but i would like to change the div as I am trying to render a stack-bar graph and I want that here user should be able to increase the div so that he/she can see the graph more clearly.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle with your code so we can see and test ?

Comment: here is the fiddle [graph](http://jsfiddle.net/pooja1110/T9py8/1/)

what i want here is to increase the div size so that it increase the graph also not just the div.

Comment: Could you set your fiddle with testing data instead of <php> vars ?

Comment: alright check out my answer, I tested on your fiddle and it works (I updated it so you can check). How do you want the user to resize the div? Like, how do you set the new width? I'm sure it isn't random

Comment: I want to increase the height and width with 500px on every click event.

Answer (score 1):

To change div size you can try this :

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({height:'+=50', width:'+=50'})
 })
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/T9py8/)

Answer (score 0):

You can reflow your chart on click event. I'm assuming you are clicking your chart:

```
$('#container').click(function () {
    // Set size here according to your demands and then reflow your chart
    $( this ).width( $( this ).width() + 200 );
    $( this ).height( $( this ).height() + 200 );
    $( this ).highcharts().reflow();
});
```

- Reference:

  http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-reflow/

Comment: hey here is it not possible to re-size the chart till user wants instead of having to re-size it only once.

Comment: Here the main idea is to reflow the chart. You haven't defined the resize conditions, so i just gave a simple example. If you want a more specific answer, then you should be more specific.

Comment: right,
here I want to re-size it till user wants(recursively)

Comment: Check my edited answer, it will increase width and height by 200px on every click. If you want to stop increment in some size, then you should add some conditions.